# Get month but needs to reset at the end of the year with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping you could help me with this. I am trying to create a script that will get month but needs to reset at the end of the year. The purpose is I want to let users know that a service will end in a month. What I have works fine until I get to the end of the year. I'm having a hard time thinking through the solution to calculate the end of the year, causing the script to reset to January. I hope articulated what I'm trying to do. Any help is appreciated. Here's what I have so far

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", 
"May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
var d = new Date();
var mon = d.getMonth()+1;
var oneMonth = months[mon];
```

Comment: I'm unclear what needs to be reset where.

Comment: As a side note  getMonth() returns a value from 0 to 11, so you'll never get "January" in the expression months[mon] since you are adding 1 to getMonth().

Comment: …and since it returns 0 - 11, it perfectly matches the array you already have…

Comment: @deceze this question is not unclear. The OP is trying to add one to the month.

Comment: @deceze it seems clear enough that OP is looking to find out how to go back to January? `getMonth` may return 0-11, adding one to it would put it out of the bounds of the array

Comment: @Oliver Is the intention here to output *the next month*? Then I see a point. Otherwise, `months[d.getMonth()]` will always work without needing to reset anything.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Question is totally clear. OP *will* get January when it's December (11) and adds 1 month to that with the correct modulus.

Comment: @deceze but we're not seeing `months[d.getMonth()]` here; we're seeing `months[d.getMonth() + 1]`. That may be out of bounds.

Comment: @Oliver And to me it's unclear why that 1 is being added. Is it because `getMonth` returns a 0-indexed value, or because OP want's *the next month*. Simply using the words "the next month" in the question would have greatly clarified that.

Comment: @deceze You're 100% correct; adding the words "the next month" would have clarified what's being asked. Perhaps a more appropriate response would have been to comment as such, rather than putting the question on hold?

Comment: @deceze "service will end **in a month**" seems to mention this. Plus, the code is pretty self-explanatory (`d.getMonth()+1;`).

Comment: Just want to say, this community is awesome. Thanks for the quick responses. I will try these suggestion and +1 the solution. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%` to reset:

```
var mon = (d.getMonth()+1)%months.length;
```

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
  "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var dt = new Date('2018/11/20');
console.log(months[((dt.getMonth() + 1) % months.length)]);
console.log(months[((dt.getMonth() + 2) % months.length)]);
console.log(months[((dt.getMonth() + 3) % months.length)]);
```

OR, just use Date#setMonth()

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
  "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var dt = new Date('2018/12/31');
dt.setMonth(1 + dt.getMonth());
console.log(months[dt.getMonth()]);

dt.setMonth(2 + dt.getMonth());
console.log(months[dt.getMonth()]);
```

Comment: The `setDate()` example only appears to work for an offset of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `%` operator to wrap your offset around the array. Modulus is a very important array tool in that you can add any offset and you'll remain in bounds of valid array indices 0-11.

In your case, `(11 + 1) % 12 === 0` where `11` is December, `0` is January, `1` is the number of months you want to step into the future and `12` is the number of months in the year.

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", 
"May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
var d = new Date();
var mon = d.getMonth() + 1;
var oneMonth = months[mon%months.length];
console.log(mon, oneMonth);
```

Comment: You realise that `getMonth` will return an integer in the range 0-11, and that the array contains the indices 0-11…? At what point is a modulus necessary?

Comment: @Mark ***If*** the goal is to output *the next month*… okay, sure. I'd rather wrap `mon` around then though so it's always in the range 0-11.

Comment: @deceze It seems clear to me that the goal is to output the next month. This will **not** always be `0-11`: `var mon = d.getMonth() + 1;`

Comment: @Mark That's what I'm saying: apply the modulus at that line so `mon` *will* always be in the range 0-11.

Comment: Sure @deceze , however, I think it's a matter of style whether you add the modulus at that line or when indexing into the array as this answer does.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers give you a way to do this with vanilla javascript; if you're interested in using a library, then [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) isn't a bad choice, and makes it quite easy to work with dates.

```js
const {
  parse,
  addMonths,
  getMonth,
} = dateFns;

const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", 
"May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]

const newDate = getMonth(addMonths(
  parse(new Date()),
  1
))

const janDate = getMonth(addMonths(
  parse(new Date()),
  4
))

console.dir(months[newDate])
console.dir(months[janDate])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.29.0/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```